# Matrix representation of spin-1/2 operators in Sakurai

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, notation

Hello and thanks for reading.

I'm an undergrad working through the first chapter of Sakurai's text and was 
going through the principles of the spin-1/2 system. The author demonstrates  closure and then gives the spinor forms of the operators in matrices. He explains this step as follows:

"In constructing the matrix representations of the angular momentum operators, it is customary to label the column (row) indices in descending order of angular momentum components; that is, the first entry corresponds to the maximum angular momentum component, the second to the next highest, and so forth."

I have two questions regarding this statement.

1. How does one go about labelling w.r.t components? Let me for example pick up the Sz and S+ operators. How do their matrices satisfy above rule?
2. Does this statement hold for any and all q.m. operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to construct a matrix representation one needs an ordering of the basis states.  In this case this ordering is $m_s=1/2$ and then $m_s=-1/2$. Thus, the matrix representation of an operator $\hat O$ will be
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\langle 1/2\vert \hat O \vert  1/2\rangle & \langle 1/2\vert \hat O \vert  -1/2\rangle\\
\langle -1/2\vert \hat O \vert  1/2\rangle & \langle -1/2\vert \hat O \vert  -1/2\rangle\end{array}\right)
$$
where the first column contains only kets with $m_s=1/2$, the second column only kets with $m_s-1/2$, the first row only bras with $m_s=1/2$ and the second row only bras with $m_s=-1/2$.

Thus for instance, if $\hat  O=\hat S_z$ you would get
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1/2&0 \\
0&-1/2\end{array}\right)
$$

If you have chosen the order $\{\vert -1/2\rangle,\vert 1/2\rangle$ then your $\hat S_z$ would look like 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-1/2&0 \\
0&1/2\end{array}\right)
$$
There is no set rule for the ordering, although in angular momentum one often start with $m_s=L$ and then goes down to $m_s=-L$.  The key point is that of course the same ordering must be used for rows and columns.

In the case of eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, one often starts with the eigenvector corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue as the first in the list, increasing in eigenvalues so the eigenvector with largest eigenvalue ss the last in the list.

Comment: This was helpful. It's a hard book to follow and I need all the assistance I can get, so the quick response is iluminating.